# Get specific HTML table element with google script

Tags: javascript, html

I've been looking for this same question but none of them seems to have an accurate answer.
I think this should be simpler, I want to get a specific cell from an HTML table in a website using google script.
It needs to work inside google script so pls dont suggest =importhtml, although that's exactly the function I'm looking for.

This is a website example https://prestadores.pami.org.ar/result.php?c=6-2-1-1&beneficio=110313900302&parent=00&vm=2

I need to get the date next to the FECHA DE NACIMIENTO cell, but I dont want to do messy things like indexOf since I have to do it with a few more values.

```
<table width="480" border="0" cellpadding="3" style="margin-left: 40px;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>APELLIDO Y NOMBRE:</p></td>
                <td class="grisClaro"><p>PEREZ JUANA ANTONIA </p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>TIPO BENEFICIARIO:</p></td>
                <td class="crema"><p>JUBILACION</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>N? BENEFICIO:</p></td>
                <td class="grisClaro"><p>110313900302</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>FECHA DE NACIMIENTO:</p></td>
                <td class="crema"><p>08/03/1922</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>NACIONALIDAD:</p></td>
                <td class="grisClaro"><p>ARGENTINA</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>PAIS:</p></td>
                <td class="crema"><p>ARGENTINA</p></td>
            </tr>
<tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>UGL:</p></td>
                <td class="crema"><p>LANUS</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>DOCUMENTO:</p></td>
                <td class="grisClaro"><p>DNI123456</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>SEXO:</p></td>
                <td class="crema"><p>FEMENINO</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>ESTADO CIVIL:</p></td>
                <td class="grisClaro"><p>SEPARADO/A LEGAL</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>VENCIMIENTO AFILIACION:</p></td>
                <td class="crema"><p></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>UNIDAD OPERATIVA:</p></td>
                <td class="grisClaro"><p>NO ASIGNADA</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>ALTA:</p></td>
                <td class="crema"><p>01/09/1982</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>BAJA:</p> </td>
                <td class="grisClaro"><p>10/10/2013</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="gris"><p>OTRA OBRA SOCIAL:</p></td>
                <td class="crema"><p>NO</p></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery's contains selector, it can be done like the following easily.

```
let td = $('table td.gris:contains("FECHA DE NACIMIENTO")');
console.log(td);
let theDate = td.next('td').text();
console.log(theDate);
```

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I don't know what to do with your code, where do I put the html? Also, google script doesn't like the **let** keyword, can I use var instead?

Comment: `$('table')` is the jQuery selector here.

Comment: I didnt know what jQuery was until seconds ago ;( I dont know what you mean

Comment: @VijayJoshi this is not clear. Benjamin is using google script. Therefore, you need to provide your answer using a google script